# What type of time dependent measurement would be the same whole over the world?

Tags: time, measurements

What type of periodic measurement would be the same all over the world at the same time?

What I mean is there a phenomena that is observed similarly all over the world at the same moment. A measurement that any static frame of reference on earth's surface will agree on.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, please clarify.

Comment: If by the world you men the universe, then the peak frequency of the cosmic microwave background. If not periodic, then also the Hubble time. If by the world you mean the Earth, then an atomic clock.

Comment: If you mean is there some way of syncing clocks across the world - then there are periodic astronomical signals that can be detected by the part of the world that has them in view - but you still have to account for the different distances (and so light arrival times) for different parts of the Earth

Answer (score 1):

My 1st thought was the Solar Cycle--which is slow, but certainly observable Earth-wide. After reading your comment, I am going with pulsars. They are not just Earth wide, they are solar system (and beyond) -wide. Spacecraft signals are detected at widely separated points on Earth and the pulsar timing can be used to correct for un-modled atmospheric delays (delta-DORs)--leading to phenomenal interplanetary navigation.

Also: so-called Pulsar Timing Arrays use differential detection over long baselines to detect gravitational waves.

Comment: Can you please add some links to explain the new terms you mentioned.

Comment: last time I added a link I got down voted b/c links "aren't forever"--though I'm betting on wikipedia over SE for longevity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-DOR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar_timing_array

Comment: If you don't explain the term, at least include a link, that's my opinion